# Torque box - deploy additional jar file (rvm)

Tags: deployment, db2, jrubyonrails, torquebox

I have Jruby on rails application connected with DB2 C-Express. My problem is that the torquebox is not able to find the additional jar driver which I am using to connect the database and the application.

I have [found](http://markmail.org/thread/vt5hexswp3ofgrgg#query%3a+page:1+mid%3azaovqokxjerpi3l7+state%3aresults) that if you have torque box install you should add this jar in the

```
torquebox-current/jboss/server/default/lib
```

folder. The problem is that when I install the torque box following the official [documentation](http://torquebox.org/builds/getting-started/first-steps.html#first-steps-mac-linux) I use the "First Steps with RVM" way and I have not got the folder mention above - I just have the torque box gem.

What's the way to point the torque box gem where the jar is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After deep looking through the jboss and TorqueBox files I was not able to solve the issue. Fortunately, I've got some help from torque box  - [IRC Channel](http://torquebox.org/community/).

If you want to use db2 with WEBRICK you need to copy db2jcc.jar and db2jcc_license_cu.jar to jruby/lib (~/.rvm/rubies/jruby-*/lib) directory.

The good thing about TorqueBox is that

> TorqueBox automatically adds any jar files under the applications lib/
>   directory to the classpath of your application

So, just copy these files into your application lib/ directory.